# mySQL count frequency of one-many links

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables:

```
people
=======
id
name

jobs
=====
id
jobname
person_id
```

Person may have many jobs.

I want to count the frequency of the number of jobs people have. So for example
10 people have 0 jobs,
15 people have 1 job,
3 people have 2 jobs,
2 people have 3 jobs

I am able to get a count of the number of jobs per person as per:

```
SELECT person.id, count(jobs.id) as jobcount
FROM jobs
WHERE person.id = jobs.person_id
GROUP BY person.id
ORDER BY trancount

personid   jobcount
 1          1
 2          1
 3          2
 ...
```

But I am stuck at summing these to get a frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you group them in an outer select statement?

```
SELECT jobcount, COUNT(peoplecount) FROM (
  SELECT person.id as peoplecount, count(jobs.id) as jobcount
  FROM jobs
  WHERE person.id = jobs.person_id
  GROUP BY person.id
) AS frequency GROUP BY jobcount
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. I just had to add an alias for the derived table, like so:

    SELECT jobcount, COUNT(peoplecount) FROM (
      SELECT person.id as peoplecount, count(jobs.id) as jobcount
      FROM jobs
      WHERE person.id = jobs.person_id
      GROUP BY person.id
    ) dummyalias
    GROUP BY jobcount